# Make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified. (A Curious Moon Book)

Tags: postgresql, makefile

I am using makefile in windows. My makefile code is:

```
DB=enceladus
BUILD=${CURDIR}/build.sql
SCRIPTS=${CURDIR}/scripts
CSV='${CURDIR}/../../data/master_plan.csv'
MASTER=$(SCRIPTS)/import.sql
NORMALIZE = $(SCRIPTS)/normalize.sql 

all: normalize
    psql $(DB) -f $(BUILD)

master:
    @cat $(MASTER) >> $(BUILD)

import: master
    @echo "COPY import.master_plan FROM $(CSV) WITH DELIMITER ',' HEADER CSV;" >> $(BUILD)

normalize: import
    @cat $(NORMALIZE) >> $(BUILD)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(BUILD)
```

Which results to:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf C:/Users/zecha/cassini_data/curious_data/code/02- 
normalize/build.sql, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I dont know how to code in MAKE. I just downloaded GnuWin32 and put it on my path.

Comment: The `rm` command is a POSIX command.  You would find it on a POSIX system like GNU/Linux or MacOS.  It doesn't exist on Windows, so you can't use it on Windows (unless you install some extra facility like MinGW or whatever, that adds this command).

Comment: Basically you can't just take a makefile written for POSIX systems, download make, and run the makefile on Windows and expect it to work.  Makefiles run a lot of system tools and if you are on Windows then none of the standard POSIX system tools are available, even if you got `make`.

Comment: I now installed MinGW and tried to replace `cat` with `type`. now a new error has emerged. When I do a command 'make' this error shows. 
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: *** [master] Error 1`

Comment: "The syntax of the command is incorrect" is being printed by the windows shell, not by make.  Whatever changes you made, are not correct.  Every command line that appears in a makefile recipe, should be runnable in a Windows `cmd.exe` shell and not get an error.  If you can't run it by hand, then `make` can't run it either.